# Powershell get file from latest directory

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script to get the lines from a file named with yesterday's date and to send those lines to a file. The trick is that I have to search in the latest created directory as there are many directories in the root directory.

I have a root directory `C:\Orders` containing many subdirs named `Orders 2014.01.02`, `Orders 2014.01.04`, `Orders 2014.01.06` etc, containing thousands of txt files and in one particular `orders.txt` i have lines like this:

```
2014.01.02 Shipping order cost ....
2014.01.02 Order by phone
2014.01.03 Prepaid ..
etc ..
```

So I need a script that goes to the directory Orders with latest day, lets say `Orders 2014.01.06`, and will copy all the lines that begin with previous day's date and send it to me.

I have managed to make a script to get the lines from file in the latest directory and to send it to me via mail with attachment using this script:

```
Get-Content "C:\Orders\Orders 2014.01.06\orders.txt" | Where-Object {$_.StartsWith((Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd"))} | Out-File "C:\Orders\Result_orders.txt"
```

The thing is that this is not flexible as I have to manually change the latest subfolder in the line every time there is a new folder.

I have another line of code that shows me the latest subfolder in a root folder:

```
gci C:\Orders | where-object { $_.PSIsContainer} | sort CreatiionTime -desc | select -f 1
```

This line shows me the folder with the latest  date from which I want to get results.
The problem is that I cannot make both lines work in a script. I have tried to combine them, but could not do it. I have tried to make a second command as a variable like:

```
$since_folder = gci C:\Orders\ | where-object { $_.PSIsContainer} | sort CreatiionTime -desc | select -f 1
```

and then call it from the first line of script like:

```
Get-Content "$since_folder\orders.txt" | Where-Object {$_.StartsWith((Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd"))} | Out-File "C:\Orders\Result_orders.txt"
```

but it does not seem right and it does not work. Actually I am getting an email after I run the last script but I don't get the attachment. I only get it if I run:

```
Get-Content "C:\Orders\Orders 2014.01.06\orders.txt" | Where-Object {$_.StartsWith((Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd"))} | Out-File "C:\Orders\Result_orders.txt"
```

Can anyone help me with that script, it is probably very simple but I am hitting a wall here.

Comment: If the lines in your orders.txt file actually start with date formatted like 2014.01.21 then your `StartsWith()` method won't work because you have specified a `DateTime.ToString()` format of `yyyyDDmm`. This basically means that you're looking for a string that starts with `20140121` when the line actually starts with `2014.01.21` and thus you will get no results. Is that the actual format you're using in your txt file?

Comment: Hi, you are absolutely right. The format in the file is 20140121, i made a mistake with it while writing the post.

Comment: I have that part working, i can fetch the lines from file that have yesterday's date and to sand it to me.But i have to change the name of the subdir manually when i am using:
Get-Content "C:\Orders\Orders 2014.01.06\orders.txt" | Where-Object {$_.StartsWith((Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd"))} | Out-File "C:\Orders\Result_orders.txt"
what i want to do is to make the powershell automatically to find the directory with most recent date.
i can use:
gci C:\Orders\ | where-object { $_.PSIsContainer} | sort CreatiionTime -desc | select -f 1, but how can i connect it to first one

Answer (score 1):

The following will return the name of most recently created directory in the current folder:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | sort -Descending -Property CreationTime | select -first 1 name
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. I got this one, i have it in the post above, i just cant make it work altogether with get-content command..

Comment: IMHO Should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$since_folder = gci C:\Orders\ |
    where { $_.PSIsContainer } |
    sort CreationTime -desc |
    select -f 1

$filename = [System.IO.Path]::Combine( $since_folder.FullName, "orders.txt" ) # ends up with c:\orders\Orders 2014.10.21\orders.txt

Get-Content $filename |
    where { $_.StartsWith((Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd")) } |
    Out-File "C:\Orders\Result_orders.txt"
```

This gets you out of the hardcoded path.

Answer (score 0):

The following retrieves the most recently created directory, filters for "orders.txt", and then retrieves the lines that match yesterday's date based on the updated pattern provided:

```
gci "C:\Orders" |
  Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer} |
  sort CreationTime -desc |
  select -f 1 |
  gci -Filter "orders.txt" |
  Get-Content |
  Where-Object { $_.StartsWith((Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd")) } |
  Out-File "C:\Orders\Result_orders.txt"
```

PowerShell 3 allows filtering for directories directly in Get-ChildItem:

```
gci "C:\Orders" -Directory |
  sort CreationTime -desc |
  select -f 1 |
  gci -Filter "orders.txt" |
  Get-Content |
  Where-Object { $_.StartsWith((Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd")) } |
  Out-File "C:\Orders\Result_orders.txt"
```

Comment: The gci here seems completely unnecessary, since OP stated orders.txt will exist. Could you explain why this is better than simply using the Path.Combine?

Comment: Get-Content doesn't take a path as input, it needs the file to be piped via `gci` otherwise it throws an error: `The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the 
command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters 
that take pipeline input.`

Comment: Get-Content c:\test.txt works just fine...

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787.aspx

Comment: Yes but `c:\test.txt | Get-Content` does not. If you want to use `Get-Content` from a pipeline you need to use e.g. `gci c:\test.txt | gc`

Comment: Sure. If you insist on piping every command, you have to use gci. It's wasteful to gci in a large directory, but there's probably absolutely no performance concern in this case.

Comment: Without actually testing, I suspect that `gci` is performant enough in large directories to not be an issue. With respect to the piping of the commands, the OP stated `I have tried to combine them, but could not do it` - I am just demonstrating that it is possible to effectively combine both his requirements into a single line using pipes. Obviously there is little opportunity to capture and recover from errors that might occur which would be afforded by splitting the script across multiple lines.